# Split input file on pattern match - fasta name rows

Tags: r, split, fasta

I have a file (from MUMmer actually), that looks like this (short version):

```
> H_pyloriJ99_Eslice
    9375        47        28
    9446       118        28
    9535       207        26
    9574       246        23
    9598       270        30
    9629       301        33
    9676       348        29
    9727       399        48
> H_pyloriJ99_Eslice Reverse
   30792    228877        20
   31481    114368        20
   34371    211370        36
   34408    211333        56
   34474    211267        31
   34531    211210        20
   34558    211183        28
   34623    211118        33
   34657    211084        29
```

I would like to read this file into two R data frames splitting by the fasta header (starting with the >). Thank you.
jahn

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the whole file using `readLines`, find the lines starting with `>` and than `assign` what `read.table` returns for the following lines to the name.

```
x <- readLines(file("data.txt"))
i <- c(grep("^>", x), length(x)+1)
for(j in seq_len(length(i)-1)) {
    assign(substring(x[i[j]], 3) ,read.table(text=x[(i[j]+1):(i[j+1]-1)]))
}
H_pyloriJ99_Eslice
#    V1  V2 V3
#1 9375  47 28
#2 9446 118 28
#3 9535 207 26
#4 9574 246 23
#5 9598 270 30
#6 9629 301 33
#7 9676 348 29
#8 9727 399 48
`H_pyloriJ99_Eslice Reverse`
#     V1     V2 V3
#1 30792 228877 20
#2 31481 114368 20
#3 34371 211370 36
#4 34408 211333 56
#5 34474 211267 31
#6 34531 211210 20
#7 34558 211183 28
#8 34623 211118 33
#9 34657 211084 29
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *awk* (adapted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350533/16560)):

```
#$ ls
# test.txt

awk '{if(gsub(/^> /,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name".txt"}}' test.txt

#$ ls
# H_pyloriJ99_Eslice Reverse.txt
# H_pyloriJ99_Eslice.txt
# test.txt
#
#$ head -n2 H_pyloriJ99_Eslice.txt
#    9375        47        28
#    9446       118        28
```